# Rspec assigning local variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Just wondering if there's a way to access local variables in rspec without turning them into instance variables? To explain my issue:

I have the following action:

```
  def queue_due_mail
    payments = Payment.due_soon.where(:send_reminder => true)
    payments.each do |p|
      PaymentMailer.delay.reminder_email(p)
      p.send_reminder = false
      p.save
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

And, in my spec, I want to run something like this:

```
it "should assign nearly due payments to payments" do
  Payment.stub_chain(:due_soon, :where) { [mock_payment] }
  get :queue_due_mail
  assigns[:payments].should eq([mock_payment])
end
```

The problem is that the assigns[:payments] call only works if I turn the local variable 'payments' into '@payments'. This isn't a major problem, but I'd rather not have my rspec tests influence by actual code.

So, is there a way to reference local variables in rspec assigns?

Cheers...

Comment: Offtopic: When redirecting, use `_url` instead of `_path`; [HTTP RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30).

Comment: I don't know how you do this but I think that might be because there's too much coupling between test and code in what you're trying to do.  Do you really need to test that a local variable gets assigned?  Surely what you really want to check is that the PaymentMailer receives the correct method calls and the mock_payment gets send_reminder set to false.  The detailed implementation doesn't actually matter because no other code should know about the payments variable.

Comment: *nods* Yep - fair point, Nick. Still, curious as to whether it's possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

basically no. Think of it as black-box testing. rspec tests what goes into or out of a method (a controller action is a method). Any local variables *should* be thrown away at the end of the method - therefore can't be tested when the method-call is over.